# How to make Fibonacci series to print out single digit

Tags: c

Below is a small project for my year one submission. But in that series, an odd number input doesn't print that number of numbers from the series, instead, it adds one to the odd number, which then becomes an even number, then print out that number of numbers from the series. I want to enable it to accept odd numbers too. How do do that? I thought of having two while loops, but i am unsure.

My code (without the header files and the main functions)**:**

```
                int N;
                printf("Welcome to Fibonacci Series Mode.\n\nEnter how many numbers do you want from the series, from the start (Only Even Numbers): ");
                scanf("%d", &N);
                float x = 0;
                float y = 1;
                float xy;
                int F = 1;
                while ( F <= N ){
                    printf("\n%.0lf", x);
                    Sleep(250);
                    printf("\n%.0lf", y);
                    Sleep(250);
                    xy = x + y;
                    y += xy;
                    x = xy;
                    F++;
                }
```

Comment: print a single number inside the loop

Comment: @pmg The what about the second number, Both numbers must exist to print a complete series. If one of the x, or y, isnt being printed, there will be missing numbers in the series.

Comment: Generally, you should output the newline at the end of the messages, not the beginning. So that `printf("\n%.0lf", x);` becomes `printf("%.0lf\n", x);`

Comment: https://ideone.com/H0JYcs --- I see... print one number and calculate one number: for fibonacci sequence you can advance one at a time.

Comment: @pmg Then How to make it print 1 at a time, odd number?

Comment: see this: https://ideone.com/wpEzDm

Comment: @pmg, Ouh. yea. But what if the person want one number? 0 and 1 isnt inside the loop right, so both will get printed out.

Comment: well, you'll have to tweak that with `if`s... but notice my changes produced 9 numbers for an "input" of 7... `if (n >= 1) printf("0"); if (n >= 2) printf(" 1"); /* if (n >= 3) enter the loop */;`

Comment: @pmg Ouh, V Thank you sir. Pleased to have received your help today. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding from your code, and your question also, that is that the current code is printing only even numbers of Fibonacci Numbers. And that is true as you can see that in the while loop, there are two numbers printing in the same iteration. So, if you want an odd number of numbers from the series, you have to print one number at a time.

Also, note what is happening in your code. 
Initially `x = 0`, `y = 1` 
Then, `xy = 0 + 1 = 1`, (the third number in the Fibonacci Series)

At the next line, y gets one step ahead of `xy`.
 That is `y = y + xy`, that means if the `xy` variable holds the `n`th number in the Fibonacci Series, then, after this assignment, variable `y` holds the `n+1`th number of the series. And setting `x = xy` gets the `n` th term.

So in each iteration of the while loop, you are printing two values of the Fibonacci Series, also the variables `x` and `y` are jumping two steps forward at the same time.

To support odd integers, I would do something like following. Note I am using integer type variables as all the numbers in the Fibonacci Series are integers.

```
void print_first_n_fibo( int n ){
    int x = 0, y = 1;
    if(n == 1){
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else if(n == 2){
        printf("0\n1\n");
    }
    else{
        int current_term = 3;
        while(current_term <= n){
            int xy = x + y;
            printf("%d\n",xy);
            x = y;
            y = xy;
            current_term++;
        }
    }

}
```

This function is generalized. It prints any first `n` terms of the Fibonacci Series, regardless of `n` being even or odd.